# random slope only for certain level in mixed model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a model of the form

```
lmer(y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + I(x2^2) + x3 + (x3|level1/level2))
```

If I want `x1` to vary depending on the level1 and 2

```
lmer(y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + I(x2^2) + x3 + (x3 + x1 + I(x1^2)|level1/level2))
```

How do I allow `x1 + I(x1^2)` to vary only according to level1 and not level2.
Is  the following the correct way of specifying it?

```
lmer(y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + I(x2^2) + x3 + (x3|level1/level2) + (x2 + I(x2^2)|level1))
```